# Ffmpeg ouputting empty file to s3 when editing a remote video clip on AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to take a clip from a remote url, use ffmpeg to edit it, and save the result to s3.

I have a layer installed with ffmpeg attached to a lambda function. The lambda function runs an ffmpeg script on it and uploads the result to S3, however, the file size is either much smaller than it should be, or 0 bytes.

Locally, the code works perfectly, and it's outputting ~500kb files into lambda. I'm running python 3.9 locally as well as on the lambda.

I thought that the file was not downloading fully before ffmpeg begins processing, which would explain the much smaller output file sizes.

I tried downloading the remote file to the lambda's `/tmp` and using that as the input for ffmpeg, but I continued having the same issue with the empty file.

Here's all the code in my lambda function:

```
import json
import subprocess
import shlex
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    download_url = 'https://newslater-resources.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ca4a9d5b-691a-49cc-90aa-15636c222017.mov'

    s3 = boto3.client(
      's3',
      region_name="us-east-1",
    )

    key = '/edits/%s.mov' % int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())

    command='''
      /opt/bin/ffmpeg -i %s \
        -vf "crop=w=in_h*9/16:h=in_h,scale=1080x1920" \
        -vcodec libx264 \
        -crf 23 \
        -preset veryfast \
        -c: a copy \
        -s 1080x1920 \
         - -y
    ''' % (download_url)

    split_command = shlex.split(command)

    p1 = subprocess.run(split_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    response = s3.put_object(Body=p1.stdout, Bucket='edited-clips', Key=key)

    signed_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
      ClientMethod='get_object',
      Params={
        'Bucket': 'edited-clips',
        'Key': key,
      } 
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not massively familiar with Python but is `subprocess.run` synchronous? As in, will that line wait until the command has finished?

Comment: Based on some testing and reading through the docs it really seems like it is synchronous. I agree that it seems like something being run async is the most likely culprit though!

Comment: Do a log of `1.stdout` - what is the result right after that `subprocess.run` command?

Comment: print(p1.stdout) right after the run shows: `b''`

Comment: What is the output of that locally with the same input?

Comment: It's `b''` as well, and the script is now generating empty files on my local machine. I'm starting to think this might actually be an issue where ffmpeg is failing silently and not an issue with lambda.


**UPDATE:** I was able to get it working again. printing p1.stdout produces a long string in this case.

Comment: In both cases? Is the output the same in both cases with the same input?

Comment: No I'm now getting different outputs locally and in lambda
*Locally*
print(p1.stdout) prints a long string (I forget what it's called, but its def the content of the video) and outputs the correctly modified video
*Lambda*
print(p1.stdout) prints an empty string and outputs an empty video file

Comment: What about the output of `split_command`? I'm trying to see what bit is differing or if the  `subprocess.run` is to blame.

Comment: The output is the same on both unfortunately. I've been doing more digging and it is starting to seem like FFMPEG is failing silently. I'm planning on trying to spin up a docker container with everything working and pushing that to a Lambda.